# Read HTML Response using SSL_read() in C, HTTP/1.0

Tags: c, http, openssl, httpresponse

I read HTML response from a website using SSL_read() in C. I used HTTP/1.0 in request message. Here is my function:

```
void Reveive_response(char *resp, SSL *ssl, int body_required) {

char header[1048576];
char body[1048576];
int bytes;                      // number of bytes actually read
int received = 0;               // number of bytes received
int i, line_length;
char c[1];

memset(header, '\0', sizeof(header));               // header assign = '\0'
memset(body, '\0', sizeof(body));                   // body assign = '\0'

/***********Try to read byte by byte***********/

i = 0;
line_length = 0;                                // to check length of each line
do {
    bytes = SSL_read(ssl, c, 1);                // read 1 byte to c[0]
    if (bytes  <= 0) break;                     // read fall or connection closed
    if (c[0] == '\n') {                         // if '\n'
        if (line_length == 0) break;            // empty line, so end header
        else line_length = 0;                   // else reset for new line
    } else if ( c[0] != '\r') line_length++;    // inc length
    header[i++] = c[0];                     // add to header
    received += bytes;                          // count
} while (1);
fprintf(f, "%s\n", header);
//printf("Received...%d\n", received);
printf("\n##### Header DONE #####\n");
strcpy(resp, header);                               // return via resp

/***********************************************/

/********Then try to read body if needed********/

char *buf = malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
if (body_required) {//read body
    do {
        memset(buf, '\0', 1024*sizeof(char));
        bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buf, 1024);
        if (bytes <= 0) break;
        //printf("Wait : ");
        //getchar();
        printf("%s", buf);
        strcat(body, buf);
    } while (1);
    printf("\n##### Body DONE #####\n");
}
fprintf(f, "%s\n", body);
free(buf);

/***********************************************/
fprintf(f, "=============================\n");

}
```

The header is OK. But when I want to read body, I received this:
[image]

I don't know where I went wrong. Any ideas? Please help.

Comment: Might be compressed, does the header contain something like `Encoding: compress, gzip` or something similar? Are you setting your` Accept-Encoding` in the request?

Comment: Thank you. I set `Accept-Encoding` in the resquest :). I fixed it.

Comment: You are welcome. Could you post how you fixed it as an answer below? It might help other people with the same problem in the future.

Comment: Nothing much :)). I just delete `Accept-Encoding` in the request.

Comment: Still, until someone (e.g. You) post this as an answer that gets accepted, this question will show up as "unanswered".